# Cannot call parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-native, ecmascript-6

This code snippet works pretty well when I remove animated class from Text component. However I couldn't figure it out why I couldn't call parent components' function from child component while I'm trying to use child component with animated api.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

class Txt extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.childButton = this.childButton.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.position = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 200, y: 400 });
  }

  childButton() {
    this.props.callback(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.childButton}>
        <Animated.Text style={{ transform: [{ translateY: this.position.y }] }}>
          button
        </ Animated.Text >
      </TouchableOpacity >
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.parentButton = this.parentButton.bind(this);
  }

  parentButton(param) {
    console.log(param);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Txt callback={this.parentButton} id="_3131" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use arrow functions for your declarations in place of `bind`.
In this case you are trying to access `this.props.callback` in `childButton` which is a closure scope that does not have a `props` property.

```
childButton = () => {
  this.props.callback(this.props.id);
}
```

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure it is doing the same thing, which is binding the class context. have a look at that  https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Comment: If you are concerned with transpilation/testability then i suggest just passing the value to `childButton` directly instead of accessing it through `props`

Comment: actually I am, but for my own project it has pretty complicated data flow in animation. I am still working on that but to post as a question I just extracted code which I am having problems.